# Why can't static_cast be used to down-cast when virtual inheritance is involved?

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance, downcast, static-cast

Consider the following code:

```
struct Base {};
struct Derived : public virtual Base {};

void f()
{
    Base* b = new Derived;
    Derived* d = static_cast<Derived*>(b);
}
```

This is prohibited by the standard (`[n3290: 5.2.9/2]`) so the code does not compile, because `Derived` *virtually* inherits from `Base`. Removing the `virtual` from the inheritance makes the code valid.

What's the technical reason for this rule to exist?

Comment: I hope that you are content with my edit.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The technical problem is that there's no way to work out from a `Base*` what the offset is between the start of the `Base` sub-object and the start of the `Derived` object.

In your example it appears OK, because there's only one class in sight with a `Base` base, and so it appears irrelevant that the inheritance is virtual. But the compiler doesn't know whether someone defined another `class Derived2 : public virtual Base, public Derived {}`, and is casting a `Base*` pointing at the `Base` subobject of that. In general[*], the offset between the `Base` subobject and the `Derived` subobject within `Derived2` might not be the same as the offset between the `Base` subobject and the complete `Derived` object of an object whose most-derived type is `Derived`, precisely because `Base` is virtually inherited.

So there's no way to know the dynamic type of the complete object, and different offsets between the pointer you've given the cast, and the required result, depending what that dynamic type is. Hence the cast is impossible.

Your `Base` has no virtual functions and hence no RTTI, so there certainly is no way to tell the type of the complete object. The cast is still banned even if `Base` does have RTTI (I don't immediately know why), but I guess without checking that a `dynamic_cast` is possible in that case.

[*] by which I mean, if this example doesn't prove the point then keep adding more virtual inheritance until you find a case where the offsets are different ;-)

Comment: +1: Made my head hurt so I won't say it's an entirely clear answer, but appears to me to be the correct one. :)

Comment: @Tomalak: thanks, it makes my head hurt a bit too, but if I think of a way to explain more clearly then I'll come back and edit.

Comment: \*cough\* ASCII diagrams! \*cough\*

Comment: @Tomalak: yeah, requires more time than I have to hand and still get to the shops during my lunch break. I'd have to actually write some classes with virtual inheritance and figure out their layouts to pin down the disparity, instead of hand-waving that part...

Comment: Indeed. It's just about more than I'm willing to do, too, though I'd still love to see it!

Comment: @Steve The only way I know of explaining the actual problem clearly is to diagram the (typical) layout in the case of `Derived` and `Derived2`.  And doing such diagrams in ASCII is a pain.

Comment: Is a `dynamic_cast` possible in general?

Comment: This explanation is not clear enough to understand. Can you please elaborate more on it?

Answer (score 22):

`static_cast` can perform only those casts where memory layout between the classes is known at compile-time. `dynamic_cast` can check information at run-time, which allows to more accurately check for cast correctness, as well as read run-time information regarding the memory layout.

Virtual inheritance puts a run-time information into each object which specifies what is the memory layout between the `Base` and `Derived`. Is one right after another or is there an additional gap? Because `static_cast` cannot access such information, the compiler will act conservatively and just give a compiler error.

---

**In more detail:**

Consider a complex inheritance structure, where - due to multiple inheritance - there are multiple copies of `Base`. The most typical scenario is a diamond inheritance:

```
class Base {...};
class Left : public Base {...};
class Right : public Base {...};
class Bottom : public Left, public Right {...};
```

In this scenario `Bottom` consists of `Left` and `Right`, where *each* has its own copy of `Base`. The memory structure of all the above classes is known at compile time and `static_cast` can be used without a problem.

Let us now consider the similar structure but with virtual inheritance of `Base`:

```
class Base {...};
class Left : public virtual Base {...};
class Right : public virtual Base {...};
class Bottom : public Left, public Right {...};
```

Using the virtual inheritance ensures that when `Bottom` is created, it contains only *one* copy of `Base` that is *shared* between object parts `Left` and `Right`. The layout of `Bottom` object can be for example:

```
Base part
Left part
Right part
Bottom part
```

Now, consider that you cast `Bottom` to `Right` (that is a valid cast). You obtain a `Right` pointer to an object that is in two pieces: `Base` and `Right` have a memory gap in between, containing the (now-irrelevant) `Left` part. The information about this gap is stored at run-time in a hidden field of `Right` (typically referred to as `vbase_offset`). You can read the details for example [here](https://ww2.ii.uj.edu.pl/~kapela/pn/cpp_vtable.html).

However, the gap would not exist if you would just create a standalone `Right` object.

So, if I give you just a pointer to `Right` you do not know at compile time if it is a standalone object, or a part of something bigger (e.g. `Bottom`). You need to check the run-time information to properly cast from `Right` to `Base`. That is why `static_cast` will fail and `dynamic_cast` will not.

---

**Note on dynamic_cast:**

While `static_cast` does not use run-time information about the object, `dynamic_cast` uses and *requires* it to exist! Thus, the latter cast can be used only on those classes which contain at least one virtual function (e.g. a virtual destructor)

Answer (score 5):

Fundamentally, there's no real reason, but the intention is that
`static_cast` be very cheap, involving at most an addition or a
subtraction of a constant to the pointer.  And there's no way to
implement the cast you want that cheaply; basically, because the
relative positions of `Derived` and `Base` within the object may change
if there is additional inheritance, the conversion would require a good
deal of the overhead of `dynamic_cast`; the members of the committee
probably thought that this defeats the reasons for using `static_cast`
instead of `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Fundamentally, there's _every_ reason.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I concur with Tomalak. The `static` in `static_cast` means a compile-time conversion for a non-null pointer.

Comment: @David Hammen It depends on what you mean by "compile-time" conversion.  `static_cast` definitely can involve some code executed at run-time, even when only pointers are involved.  But as I said, the code is fairly limited: adding or subtracting a constant from the pointer, but not looking things up in the `vtable`.  (Not sure why the down vote either, since my answer is totally correct.  But votes here seem to be pretty random anyway; I don't think they mean anything.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: I meant pretty much what you said. There will be run-time code, but it will be limited in nature: Checking for a null pointer, adding a fixed offset determined at compile time. Static cast works without RTTI. Dynamic cast in general does not. (There is some overlap; dynamic cast can be used for upcasting.)

Comment: @David That corresponds to what I understand was the intent of the committee.  Although RTTI didn't exist at the time.  Roughly, for non-virtual derivation, the generated code has to check for null, then add or subtract a constant; with virtual derivation, the constant is replaced with an entry in the `vtable`, which requires two memory accesses to get.  IMHO, they should have done it anyway; two memory accesses aren't the end of the world.  But the committee felt otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following function `foo`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int Ax;
};

struct B : virtual A
{
    int Bx;
};

struct C : B, virtual A
{
    int Cx;
};


void foo( const B& b )
{
    const B* pb = &b;
    const A* pa = &b;

    std::cout << (void*)pb << ", " << (void*)pa << "\n";

    const char* ca = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(pa);
    const char* cb = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(pb);

    std::cout << "diff " << (cb-ca) << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    C c;
    foo(c);

    B b;
    foo(b);
}
```

Although not really portable, this function shows us the "offset" of A and B. Since the compiler can be quite liberal in placing the A subobject in case of inheritance (also remember that the most derived object calls the virtual base ctor!), the actual placement depends on the "real" type of the object. But since foo only gets a ref to B, any static_cast (which works at compile time by at most applying some offset) is bound to fail.

ideone.com (http://ideone.com/2qzQu) outputs for this:

```
0xbfa64ab4, 0xbfa64ac0
diff -12
0xbfa64ac4, 0xbfa64acc
diff -8
```

Answer (score 1):

`static_cast` is a compile time construct. it checks for the validity of cast at compile time and gives an compilation error if invalid cast.

`virtual`ism is a runtime phenomenon.

Both can't go together.

C++03 Standard §5.2.9/2 and §5.2.9/9 ar relevant in this case.

> An rvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B”, where B is a class type, can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to cv2 D”, where D is a class derived (clause 10) from B, if a valid standard conversion from “pointer to D” to “pointer to B” exists (4.10), cv2 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1, **and B is not a virtual base class of D**. The null pointer value (4.10) is converted to the null pointer value of the destination type. If the rvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B” points to a B that is actually a sub-object of an object of type D, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object of type D. Otherwise, the result of the cast is undefined.

Comment: This isn't really the answer, as you can downcast with `static_cast` in e.g. `struct B {}; struct D : B {}; int main() { B* x = new D; D* y = static_cast<D*>(x); }`.

Comment: The memory layout of `Derived` is known at compile time, regardless of virtual inheritance being used. Also, polymorphism in general is a runtime phenomenon, yet you are still allowed to use `static_cast` to do things that might turn out to be undefined behavior at runtime.

Comment: @catPlusPlus: Where's the `virtual` there?

Comment: @Cat: I thin it is because the standard explicitly forbids Base class being virtual. I was just about looking for the right quote Tomalak beat me to it, Also a *nitpick* your example has no virtual.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes I see :) Actually reading the standard makes my head spin a little, I guess I can't digest it, but anyhow I try.

Comment: @Als: I think I'm starting to become immune to it, which is dizzingly worrying.

Comment: @eran: "The memory layout of Derived is known at compile time" - that's not sufficient, though (see my answer). Just because you've `static_cast` to `Derived` doesn't mean that the most-derived type of the object in question is `Derived`, and hence it might not have the layout that `Derived` has. That's what virtual inheritance means, that the `Base` sub-object isn't part of the `Derived` sub-object in classes derived from `Derived`.

Comment: The proposed answer is incorrect.  `static_cast` doesn't do any checking of validity; given something like `static_cast<Derived*>( pBase )`, if `pBase` doesn't actually have type `Derived`, the behavior is undefined.  But the `static_cast` compiles fine.

Comment: @James: No, the `static_cast` is _ill-formed_.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, this is due to classes with virtual inheritance having different memory layout. The parent has to be shared between children, therefore only one of them could be laid out continuously. That means, you are not guaranteed to be able to separate a continuous area of memory to treat it as a derived object.