# Using dynamic_cast without null check

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, null-check

Is there any purpose to using `dynamic_cast` when the return value isn't checked for `NULL`? If I'm looking at a code base, and the null check it omitted from the return value, might it have been just as well to use `static_cast`?

```
A *a = dynamic_cast<A *>(b);
foo(*a);   //might as well have used a static_cast
```

I've read all that Google affords on the matter, and it seems that checking for null is the only reason, but I've yet to see anyone come out and say "dynamic_cast without a null check is a waste of cycles (and a possible bloating of the code with RTTI)."

Edit: It's been put to me that if there's virtual inheritance between the types, that `static_cast` would fail where `dynamic_cast` would not. In my case, that's not the case.

Comment: _If new_type is a pointer or reference to some class D and the type of expression is a pointer or reference to its non-virtual base B, static_cast performs a downcast. **This downcast is ill-formed** if B is ambiguous, inaccessible, **or virtual base (or a base of a virtual base) of D. Such static_cast makes no runtime checks to ensure that the object's runtime type is actually D**, and may only be used safely if this precondition is guaranteed by other means, such as when implementing static polymorphism._ [Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any purpose to using dynamic_cast when the return value isn't checked for NULL?

You may not check for `nullptr` if you are sure that class instance is that type by different matter. Why not to use `static_cast` in this case? You may not be able to use `static_cast` when virtual inheritance is involved. Details can be found in answers for this question: [Why can't static_cast be used to down-cast when virtual inheritance is involved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484913/why-cant-static-cast-be-used-to-down-cast-when-virtual-inheritance-is-involved)

Comment: I see. So if there was a virtual relationship between `A` and `B`, then `static_cast` would be a problem, and `dynamic_cast` would be justifiable, right? In my case, there is not.