# Pointer to subclass call correct virtual function

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  virtual void print() { std::cout << "class A" << std::endl; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
  virtual void print() override { std::cout << "class B" << std::endl; }
};

class C : public A {
public:
  virtual void print() override { std::cout << "class C" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  B obj1;

  A *ptr1 = dynamic_cast<A *>(&obj1);
  ptr1->print();

  B *ptr2 = dynamic_cast<B *>(ptr1);
  ptr2->print();

  C *ptr3 = dynamic_cast<C *>(ptr2);
  ptr3->print();
}
```

Based on my understanding, when we call virtual function of an object using pointer, it would search the virtual table of the object and call the matching function for us.

But when I tried to run the code above, it only print two "class B" (the first two calls).

And looks like the third print on ptr3 will terminate the program, can someone tell me why the third print() is failed.

Comment: Because the conversion failed and `ptr3` is a null pointer.

Comment: The object pointed to _is actually a `B`_.  No amount of casting can make `ptr3` point to a `C`.

Comment: Did you check the result of `ptr3` after converting?  `obj1` isn't a `C`.

Comment: Always check the result of `dynamic_cast`. Dereferencing a null pointer is undefined behavior. [Using dynamic_cast without null check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077902/using-dynamic-cast-without-null-check)

Comment: your understanding is a misunderstanding. That the methods are virtual is the reason that calling the method on a object of type `B` will call `B::print` and not something else, you expect the opposite, that the method to be called would change depending on what pointer you use to refer to the object.

Answer (score 0):

To call `print()` successfully on a `C` object, you need to create and point to a `C` object:

```
C obj2;
C *ptr3 = dynamic_cast<C *>(&obj2);
ptr3->print(); // This will now print "class C"
```